# Python comparing a file to load to a base file

Tags: python

I want to have a base file that I can use to compare what they give me to load. e.g the based file has name,surname,amount,etc. the file can come as sue,200,anderson,etc. without column names

How can I ensure that the given file has similar columns as per the base file?

Any one with a better thinking around this, please help.

Comment: Read two lines of two files, comparing `len(line1.split(',')) == len(line2.split(','))` will work for you ??

Comment: why not use pandas. DataFrame would be better to use here

Comment: You could validate the number of fields in the file. But you cannot validate the values in each field unless or otherwise you have a pattern.

Comment: @micxcen NO DETAILS IN COMMENTS. Please edit your question with your input(s), expected output and what you did. Keep it brief, keep it short. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

If you files will do rain more than one line you should look at the `pandas` framework and especially and the `dataframe` class to read the two files. After reading them, you could just count the number of columns and compare the number.

If each file only contains one line, this is (in my opinion) too much overhead to use; I stead you should just read each line, count the number of `,` and compare the numbers, by doing something similar to this:

```
If len(lineOfBaseFile.split(',')) == len(lineOfValueFile.split(',')):
    Everything alright, process the data
else:
    Columns do not match
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using pandas, here is what I have done.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
from IPython.display import display, HTML

filepath = "C:/WORKBOOK.XLSM"
filepath2 ="C:/slsSep20170904.csv"

df = pd.read_excel(filepath,sheetname='Table',skiprows=
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],usecols=[6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17])
df2 = pd.read_csv(filepath2,skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],usecols=
[6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17])
   if all(df['Unnamed: 11'] == df2['Unnamed: 11']):
      difference = 'it is equals to'
      print(df['Unnamed: 11'])
      print(df2.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me but I would like any other better idea to do this.

```
if (df.iloc[0][0] in df2.iloc[0][0] and 
df.iloc[0][1] in df2.iloc[0][1] and
str(df.iloc[0][2]) in str(df2.iloc[0][2]) and 
df.iloc[0][3] in df2.iloc[0][3] and 
str(df.iloc[0][4]) in str(df2.iloc[0][4]) and 
df.iloc[0][5] in df2.iloc[0][5] and
df.iloc[0][6] in df2.iloc[0][6] and
str(df.iloc[0][7]) in str(df2.iloc[0][7]) and
df.iloc[0][8] in df2.iloc[0][8] and 
df.iloc[0][9] in df2.iloc[0][9] and
df.iloc[0][10] in df2.iloc[0][10] and
df.iloc[0][11] in df2.iloc[0][11]):
    print(difference)
    df.to_csv('C:/Test.csv', index=False, 
header=False)
else:
    df= pd.DataFrame({'A' : []})
    df.to_csv('C:/Test.csv', index=False, 
header=False)
df.head()
```